# Is every non-negative test function the limit of a sequence of sums of squares of test functions?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $0\leq f\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. As shown e.g. by J.-M. Bony, F. Broglia, F. Colombini and L. Pernazza, *Nonnegative functions as squares or sums of squares*, [J. Funct. Anal. **232** (2006) 137-147](http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/bony/BBCP_jfa.pdf) (see also [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105438/square-root-of-a-positive-c-infty-function) and [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186433/square-root-of-compactly-supported-c-infinity-function)), not every such an $f$ is of the form $f=g^2$ for $g\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or even a finite sum of such. On the other hand, as mentioned in the paper above, C. Fefferman and D. H. Phong sketched a proof (*On positivity of pseudo-differential operators*, Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. **75** (1978) 4673-4674) of the fact that any $0\leq f\in\mathscr{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can be written as a sum of squares $$f=\sum^k_{j=1}g_j^2$$ with $g_j\in\mathscr{C}^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (i.e. $g_j$ is a differentiable function whose derivatives are locally Lipschitz) for all $1\leq j\leq k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. This fact was a key ingredient of the proof of the important inequality for scalar pseudodifferential operators with non-negative symbols that bears their name. For a modern, more detailed proof of the above formula, see N. Lerner, *Some Facts About the Wick Calculus*, in L. Rodino, M.W. Wong (eds.), *Pseudodifferential Operators: Quantization and Signals*, Lectures given at the C.I.M.E. Summer School held in Cetraro, Italy June 19–24, 2006 (Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics **1949**, 2008), pp. 135-174, particularly Theorem 5.2, pp. 167-172, and the discussion right after Theorem 1.1 in the paper by Bony *et alii* above on page 139. It immediately follows by multiplication by squares of smooth bump functions that the $g_j$'s may be chosen to be compactly supported if $f\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Bony *et alii* showed above that this regularity for $n\geq 4$ is sharp.

All this leads naturally to the following

> **Question:** Is every $0\leq f\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the *limit of a 
>   sequence* of sums of squares *in* $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in the latter's topology?

In other words, is the cone of non-negative elements of $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the (sequential) closure of the cone of sums of squares in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

I am particularly interested in arguments that do not rely on the result by Fefferman and Phong.

> **EDIT - Follow-up subquestion:** (suggested by André Henriques) Is every $0\leq f\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the limit of an *increasing* sequence of sums of squares in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in the latter's topology? Particularly, can $f$ be written as $$f=\sum^\infty_{j=1}g_j^2$$ with $g_j\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $j$ and convergence in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: In dimension $n=1$, we can simply modify $f$ slightly near the edges of an interval where $f>0$ to make it a square there, and then we do this for finitely many of these intervals and set $g=0$ otherwise to obtain an approximation. In general, can't we do essentially the same thing with the components of the open set $\{f>0\}$ ?

Comment: Hmm... The difficulty with your idea is that there may be points $x$ where $f(x)=0$ but the derivatives of $f$ at such $x$ may be large (such points are in the interior of $\mathrm{supp} f$, of course). It's not clear to me how to modify $f$ near $f^{-1}(0)$ so as to put it in square form (to do it away from there is easy if we use squares of smooth functions as elements of a suitable partition of unity since there simply taking the square root of $f$ is harmless) while keeping at a finite but arbitrarily large number of derivatives not too far off the derivatives of $f$ near $f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: Maybe it would have been more interesting to ask whether every $0\leq f\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the *increasing* limit of a 
sequence of sums of squares in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Or, even better, whether it can be written as $f=\sum_{j=1}^\infty g_j^2$.

Comment: I think this, if true, is bound to be (much?) harder, specially if we want convergence to take place in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, since the "cheapest" way to get the result I asked for is to keep the approximating sequence away from zero at the zeros of $f$ which are cluster points of $\{f>0\}$, as Pietro Majer proposed below. In your case, one does the opposite. A possibility would be to somehow "flatten" the approximating functions near these troublesome points, but this probably rules out convergence in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ since, again, the derivatives of $f$ may be large there.

Comment: Yes, it's going to be much harder... but only because Pietro Majer's answer was so easy.  ;-)

Comment: I've just added the follow-up subquestion you suggested. I don't know, though, if it's good form for MO to do it since I've already accepted Pietro Majer's answer, or if it is better asked as a separate question because of that...

Comment: One might also think of the Dixmier-Malliavin theorem that answers analogous questions on real Lie groups, etc.

Comment: Thanks @paulgarrett, I wasn't aware of this interesting theorem. Unfortunately, a closer look (as e.g. in https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/Dixmier-Malliavin.pdf) doesn't reveal how helpful it is for my question - it doesn't seem at all guaranteed that the rhs of the Dixmier-Malliavin formula applied to this question's context should be a sum of squares. The counterexamples discussed by Bony *et alii* and in David Speyer's answer below rather indicate that the Dixmier-Malliavin theorem is most likely not relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro  About the quoted result by Fefferman and Phong: precisely, in what topology converges the series of squares?

Comment: @PietroMajer Fefferman and Phong get a *finite* sum of squares, so the convergence is (trivially) $C^{1,1}$ but not $C^2$ since the squares cannot be $C^2$ by the results of Bony *et alii*.

Comment: ok I hadn't noticed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given  $f\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $f\ge0$ choose a $g\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $g\ge0$ such that $\mathrm{supp}(f)\subset \{g>0\}$, and let $\epsilon>0$. Then $\sqrt{f+\epsilon^2 g^2}$ is $C^\infty$: by composition, at any point where $g(x)>0$, and because it locally coincides with $\epsilon g$, at any point where $g(x)=0$.

Comment: This is fine - if $0\leq g\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is such that $\mathrm{supp} f\subset\{g>0\}$, then $0\leq f_\epsilon=f+\epsilon^2g^2=:g_\epsilon^2\rightarrow f$ in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ with $g_\epsilon=\sqrt{f_\epsilon}\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $\epsilon>0$ by your argument. I'm (even more) OK with a sum with just one square ;-) actually, I'm dumbfounded at how the answer could be this simple and how I could have missed it... Thanks!

Comment: I've just found that an argument similar to yours is sketched in L. Schwartz's proof of the Bochner-Schwartz theorem on the characterization of distributions of positive type, as done in his book "Théorie des Distributions".

Answer (score 7):

It is possible I have misunderstood the topology on $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$; I assumed it means that all the derivatives must converge. With that understanding, let $a \in (0,3]$.  I claim that  $x^4 y^2+y^4 z^2+z^4 x^2 - a x^2 y^2 z^2$ cannot be written as a sum $\sum f_i(x,y,z)^2$ of $C^3$ functions. Note that this function is nonnegative by the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

If we had $x^4 y^2+y^4 z^2+z^4 x^2 - a x^2 y^2 z^2 = \sum f_i(x,y,z)^2$ then the degree $k$ part of the Taylor series of the right hand side would converge to the degree $k$ part of the Taylor series of the left hand side. From this we see that the $f_i$ vanish up to third order and, writing $c_i$ for the cubic part of the Taylor series of $f_i$, we have $x^4 y^2+y^4 z^2+z^4 x^2 - a x^2 y^2 z^2 = \sum c_i^2(x,y,z)$. This is the standard example of a nonnegative polynomial which cannot be written as a sum of squares, so now we just hav to show that the same proof shows that it cannot be written as an infinite sum of squares.

There are no $x^6$, $y^6$ or $z^6$ terms on the right hand side, so the $c_i$ have no $x^3$, $y^3$ or $z^3$ terms. Similarly, looking at the coefficients of $x^2 y^4$, $y^2 z^4$ and $z^2 z^4$, we see that there are no $x y^2$, $y z^2$ or $z x^2$ terms. So $c_i(x,y,z) = p_i x^2 y + q_i y^2 z + r_i z^2 x + s_i x y z$. But then $-a = \sum s_i^2$, a contradiction.

Comment: In principle, the (counter)example you proposed should be compactly supported, but (as argued in my question) this can be easily achieved by multiplying everything by a squared bump function, so that's OK. That being said, recall that $f_j\rightarrow f$ in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if there is $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ compact such that $\mathrm{supp}f,\mathrm{supp}f_j\subset K$ for all $j$ and all derivatives of $f_j$ converge uniformly in $K$ to those of $f$, so one can start from a (counter)example in $\mathscr{C}^\infty$ with uniform convergence of all derivatives in compacta.

Comment: Moreover, one should probably add to your answer the (obvious but clarifying) fact that $x^4y^2+y^4z^2+z^4x^2−ax^2y^2z^2$, $a\in(0,3]$ only vanishes at the union of three straight lines $\{(t,0,0)\ |\ t\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(0,t,0)\ |\ t\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(0,0,t)\ |\ t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ due to the sharpness of the AM-GM inequality, and that one is considering the Taylor(-MacLaurin) expansion (with remainder) around $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Why the $f_i$ vanish up the third degree?

Comment: Compare the constant terms on each side to get that the constant terms of all the $f_i$ are $0$. Then compare the quadratic terms to get that the linear parts of each $f_i$ are $0$. Then compare the degree $4$ terms to get that the degree $2$ parts of each $f_i$ are zero.

Comment: Motzkin polynomial strikes again (the function given by David is the famous Motzkin's example of a non-SOS non-negative polynomial).

Answer (score 5):

The last counterexample  posted here led me to think a bit on the theme "*What can be done then?*". I came out with the following simple crank machine, that crumbles a positive $C^1_c$ function $f$ into a $C^1$ convergent series of squares, and that could also work in other ordered algebras (in fact I suspect it may be a known procedure). We may assume with no loss of generality $0\le f\le1/2$.

Consider the sequence of functions:
$$\begin{cases} g_1=f\\
g_{n+1}=g_n-g_n^2
\end{cases}$$

It is immediate by the definition that $f=\sum_{k=1}^n g_k^2 +g_{n+1}$, so that we have $f=\sum_{k=1}^\infty g_k^2$ in various senses, provided that the remainder  $g_{n}$ converges to zero in the same sense.

*Uniform convergence of $g_n$:* We have $0\le g_n\le1$ and
${1\over g_{n+1}}={1\over g_{n}}+{1\over 1-g_{n}}\ge {1\over g_{n}}+1,$ hence ${1\over g_{n}}\ge n$ and $g_n\le {1\over {n}}$.

*Uniform convergence of $\partial_i g_n$:* We have $\partial_i g_{n+1}=(1-2g_n)\partial_ig_n$. Since $0\le 1-2g_n\le1-g_n={g_{n+1}\over g_n}\le 1$ we also have $|\partial_i g_{n+1}|\le {g_{n+1}\over g_n}|\partial_ig_n|\le |\partial_ig_n|$. Iterating the latter inequalities we get

$$|\partial_i g_{n}|\le {g_{n}\over f}|\partial_if|\le|\partial_i f|$$
which immediately implies the uniform convergence of $\partial_i g_{n}$ to $0$ (indeed $\partial_i g_{n}$ converges uniformly to zero on any set $\{f\ge\epsilon\}$ and it is dominated by $|\partial_i f|$).

$$*$$

**Rmk** if for instance $f(x)=x^2+o(x^2)$ for $x\to0$ then also $g_n(x)=x^2+o(x^2)$ so that $g_n''(0)$ can't converge to zero, as illustrated in the last post.

On the other hand, by David Speyer's example, we know that, in general, for a smooth $f$, no series can't be convergent in $C^3$.

Comment: It could be the case that $C^2$ convergence fails in certain cases. Bony *et alii* (hehe) showed in the paper cited in my question that if $n\geq 4$ there is a non-negative smooth function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not a finite sum of squares of $C^2$ functions. Perhaps by mimicking their argument in a way similar to David Speyer's answer one could show that $C^2$ convergence of a would-be series of squares fails for the same counterexample.

Comment: I made a cleaner version. As to $C^2$ convergence, I'm not sure. I think $\partial_{ij}g_n$ converges uniformly to zero on any $\{f\ge\epsilon\}$ at least.

Comment: In one variable, if $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0) =c>0$, then I get that $g_n''(0)=c$ for all $n$, so $g''_n$ does not approach $0$.

Comment: I uploaded some figures in a separate answer.

Comment: This is a neat counterexample - thanks David!

Comment: @David E Speyer, yes, I also noticed that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a comment on Pietro Majer's answer, with graphics. The first figure shows $x^2$ (red) and the first five functions of Pietro's method approaching it (blue). The second figure shows the double derivatives thereof. As you can see, the functions are converging but their second derivatives are not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice graph --In fact I think second derivatives only converge to zero point-wise in $\{f>0\}$