# Is the square root of a monotonic function whose all derivatives vanish smooth?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, smoothness

Let $g:[0,\infty] \to [0,\infty]$ be a smooth **strictly** increasing function satisfying $g(0)=0$ and $g^{(k)}(0)=0$ for every natural $k$.

> Is $\sqrt g$ is infinitely (right) differentiable at $x=0$?

I know that $\sqrt g \in C^1$ at zero*, and that in complete generality, one cannot expect [for $\sqrt g$ to be even $C^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105438/square-root-of-a-positive-c-infty-function/105445#105445). However, in the counter-example given in the linked question, $g$ was not monotonic.

> Does this additional assumption of (strict) monotonicity save us? I tried to look at the literature, but did not find a treatment of this particular case.

*The proof that $\sqrt g \in C^1$ goes by rewriting $g(x)=x^2h(x)$ where $h \ge 0$ is smooth (this is possible since $g(0)=g'(0)=0$).

**Edit:**

As pointed out by Igor Rivin, it seems that theorem 2.2 (on page 639) [here (pdf)](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASNSP_2010_5_9_3_635_0.pdf) does the job. It states that
 *any* square root of $f$ "precised up to order $m$" is of class $C^m$. (The definition of a "square root precised up to order $m$" is Definition 1.1 on page 636).

This certainly settles the issue. 
However, I think it would still be nice to find a simpler approach, since here we assume much more-the strict monotonicity is a much stronger assumption than those assumed in the paper.

---

*Comment:*

If we assume that $g''>0$ in a neighbourhood of zero (which implies that $g'>0$), then $\sqrt g \in C^2$. (details below).

> I *think* that there is a chance for smoothness under the additional assumption that $g^{(k)}>0$ in a neighbourhood of zero for every $k$, but I am not sure. The calculations become quite messy even when trying to establish $\sqrt g \in C^3$.

---

*A proof $\sqrt g \in C^2$ when $g',g''>0$ near zero:* (We use these assumptions when applying L'Hôpital's rule).

$$\sqrt{g}'' = \frac{g''}{2\sqrt{g}} - \frac{(g')^2}{4g^{3/2}}.$$

Thus it is enough to prove that $(g'')^2/g\to 0$ and $(g')^4/g^3\to 0$.

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{(g'')^2}{g} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} 2\frac{g''g^{(3)}}{g'} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} 2\frac{g''g^{(4)}+(g^{(3)})^2}{g''} = 0,
$$
where in the last equality we applied  $\frac{(h')^2}{h}\to 0$ above for $h=g''$.

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{(g')^4}{g^3} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{4(g')^2g''}{3g^2} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{8(g'')^2 + 4g' g^{(3)}}{6g} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{2g' g^{(3)}}{3g} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \left(\frac{2g^{(4)}}{3} + \frac{2g''g^{(3)}}{3g'}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{2g''g^{(3)}}{3g'} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{2g^{(4)}}{3}+\frac{2(g^{(3)})^2}{3g''} = 0,$$

where in the first row we used the first calculation, and in the second we again applied $\frac{(h')^2}{h}\to 0$ to $h=g''$.

Comment: Just a comment: if all derivatives of $g$ are nonegative in a common neighborhood of zero, then $g$ can be expanded in a power series, by Bernstein theorem, and would be equal to 0. However, the question changes if the neighborhhod is allowed to depend on the derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, by the results of

*Bony, Jean-Michel; Colombini, Ferruccio; Pernazza, Ludovico*, [**On square roots of class (C^m) of nonnegative functions of one variable**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2422/2036-2145.2010.3.08), Ann. Sc. Norm. Super. Pisa, Cl. Sci. (5) 9, No. 3, 635-644 (2010). [ZBL1207.26004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1207.26004).

Here is the math review:

[image]

Clearly the condition is fulfilled in the OP (for *any* $m$).

Comment: The DOI link doesn't work for me; the journal however released the back issues on numdam for free, so here's a direct link http://www.numdam.org/article/ASNSP_2010_5_9_3_635_0.pdf

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I see that theorem 2.2 there does the job. It says "that
 *any* square root of $f$ precised up to order $m$ is of class $C^m$". (The relevant definition of a "square root precised up to order $m$" is Definition 1.1 on page 636).

Comment: Link to Numdam abstract, rather than straight to PDF:  [Bony, Colombini, and Pernazza - On square roots of class $C^m$ of nonnegative functions of one variable](http://www.numdam.org/item/ASNSP_2010_5_9_3_635_0).  (The DOI link works for me; just to have it here.)

Answer (score 4):

Extend the domain of the function $g$ to $\mathbb R$ by letting $g(x):=0$ for real $x<0$. The resulting function, which we shall still denote by $g$, is $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb R$.

[Theorem 3.5 on page 144](http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/bony/BBCP_jfa.pdf) implies that a nonnegative $C^4$ function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ has a $C^2$ square root if for any minimum $x_0$ of $f$ we have $f(x_0)=0$.

This latter condition obviously holds for our function $g$ in place of $f$ -- because $g$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and thus has no minima in $(0,\infty)$, and $g=0$ on $(-\infty,0]$.

Therefore, we can conclude that $\sqrt g$ is $C^2$ on $\mathbb R$, even without assuming that $g''>0$ in a neighborhood of zero.

Yet, this conclusion falls short of your main goal, to show that $\sqrt g$ is $C^\infty$. Looking at the proof of the mentioned Theorem 3.5, this task may be too big for a usual MO answer and may require a full-blown paper.

Comment: "... may require a full-blown paper." [Evidently Bony and collaborators thought the same](https://mathoverflow.net/a/360192/3948) :-)

Comment: Thank you. Actually I see now that theorem 3.1  on page 142 states exactly your corollary.